# Doubts about Design of Deferred Rendering shaders

Tags: opengl, 3d, deferred-rendering, deferred-shading

I'm developing a graphics engine and already have the deferred technique running, but the thing is that every model, independently of its material (with its own shader and texture) is rendering itself with the same shaders, the 1st pass of the technique that saves info into the G-Buffer, and the 2nd pass that use that info to do the lighting part.

Is this how it's supposed to be with a central deferred shader, or can each model have its own deferred pass that stores information on the G-Buffer on its own way?

Comment: No, I just meant different shaders that write to the same G-Buffer.

Comment: Good use of the two most helpful websites for finding an answer here Nic. I am of course assuming that it is you that just posted this thread too? http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/35mbo9/doubts_about_deferred_rendering_shaders/

Comment: Haha you are right sir ;)